# Iterative calculation of $e^x$

Tags: exponential-function, approximation

Is there an iterative approximation method for calculating $e^x$, which only use basic operations (add, subtract, multiply, division), and which is capable of using an initial guess?

So, I have an initial guess for $e^x$, which is already a close value, and I'd like to have a formula, which I can apply, so the guess becomes better.

Something like we have for square root: $x_{i+1}=0.5\left(\frac{n}{x_i}+x_i\right)$. If I have an initial guess $x_1$, I can apply this formula to get better and better approximation for square root.

I derived this formula for $e^n$: $x_{i+1}=x_i\left(n+1-\ln(x_i)\right)$, but unfortunately I cannot use it, as it has $\ln()$, so it is slow to compute (it doesn't worth to use this iteration, as it is faster to compute $e^x$ directly).

Note: I'd use this, as I've written in my square root example: I have a guess, and I'd like to able to apply a formula, which gives a better approximation. So unfortunately Taylor series is not a solution for my problem (as far as I understand).

Note2: The main reason of this question is how to avoid calling the math library function `exp()`. So I need a solution which is faster than `exp()`. By faster I mean "faster on a current average PC". It could be possible, because I have a good approximation to begin with. Like one can normalize an almost unit length vector faster than calculating $1/\sqrt{\mathrm{length}}$, if we approximate $1/\sqrt{\mathrm{length}}$ around one. So, I have a good approximation to $e^x$, and I'd like to apply a simple, fast formula, which makes this approximation better.

Comment: yes. the taylor series http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf

Comment: or you could use some of the limits here, the $e^k$ one for example - you could use your square button on a calculator multiple times to give an appropriate power of x https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits

Comment: @Cato: I've updated my question, hopefully it is more clear now what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: A recent question described an interesting method for calculating logarithms on a simple calculator with a square root key.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843762/how-does-calculating-this-method-of-calculating-log-on-simple-calculator-work

Comment: If you need to "avoid calculating $e^x$" then you should ask **another** question stating exactly what it is your problem and what constraints and what you have tried to solve it. However, you already have an iteration for $e^x$ which just requires computing $\ln(x)$.

Comment: I agree completely -- a question titled "Iterative calculation of $e^x$" should not morph into something whose goal is to *not* calculate $e^x$.

Comment: @JohnHughes: I **want** to calculate $e^x$, but faster than the library `exp()`. It can be possible, as I have an initial, good guess for its value. See the vector normalization example. I'd like to achieve the same for $e^x$.

Comment: @Somos: Sorry if my intent wasn't clear enough, I hope it's clear now

Comment: @geza Your second note changed the direction of your question substantially. What is the precision of your initial estimate (is it provided by hardware?), and what is the desired precision of your exponential? If it is just double precision, there is no iterative scheme that will be faster. Look into polynomial minimax approximation instead. You can find several examples of fast `exp()` implementations on StackOverflow. Your programming environment may already offer a faster `exp()` version at some moderate reduction in accuracy, so check the documentation.

Comment: OK, so now you've told us you want to calculate $e^x$, and that you *don't* want to calculate $e^x$. This is getting silly. I think you should consider using the word "approximate" (as a verb), rethink your question until you can state it really clearly, and ask it again as a new question. I also personally think you should accept Somos's answer, because it correctly answers the question you mistakenly asked, but that's up to you.

Comment: @JohnHughes: Can you explain please, what is not clear about the current form of the question?

Comment: Nope. I'm done here.

Comment: @njuffa: I'm really sorry about that. But I don't think that the current question is contradictory to the first version of it. I admit, that the first version wasn't clear enough, but it had the square root example, which is the same what I want to achieve. Clearly, Taylor series is not iterative in the sense of my square root example, so I don't understand why people said Taylor.

Comment: @geza: The answer I upvoted was "Use the AGM" because your initial question seemed to imply that you were looking for results with arbitrary and high precision. However, computing $\exp(x)$ via the AGM is *not* an efficient method if low precision is all that is needed. For future questions, please make sure to provide *all* relevant information in the initial question, instead of adding it in bits and pieces. Based on what I know now, your question seems a much better fit for Stackoverflow (which provides multiple fast implementations of `exp()`, some of which I contributed).

Comment: @njuffa: the error of my initial estimate at most 1%. I don't want to determine the desired precision. All I want to have is a formula, which makes the approximation better. If the result is not good enough, I'll apply another iteration. Of course, I don't want to apply a lot of iterations, as the goal is to be faster than `exp`. Unfortunately, the mentioned `exp()` implementations are slower than the hypothetical formula (if it exists), like `1/sqrt(length)` is slower than the simple approximation of it, which is just a subtraction and a multiplicaton (around 1).

Comment: @njuffa: Sorry about that, in my background, 32-bit/64-bit floating points are the default, not arbitrary precision. If I wanted that, I'd mentioned it. I don't seek for a fast `exp()`, but an iterative math formula, which converges to `exp(x)`, that's why I asked this question here, because it is a math question.

Comment: @njuffa: I try to provide all relevant information, it is just I have a different background, with maybe other defaults like people have here. Yes, AGM is not for this problem, that's why I didn't accept that answer, but of course I appreciate the work Somos put into that answer (and all the others, of course).

Comment: @geza When computing mathematical functions, the choice of algorithm is *not* independent of the desired precision if a fast implementation is required (which you belatedly stated is crucial for your use case). If you start with something like Schraudolph's approximation, and you need results accurate to IEEE-754 single precision or double precision, there is *no* iterative solution of the kind you desire that fits the bill. Use the fastest implementation available on your platform (e.g. compiler "fast math" switch), or roll your own implementation based on minimax polynomial approximation.

Comment: @njuffa: the desired precision is dependent of the problem. Maybe with one iteration, I got the result I need, maybe I need two, etc. That's why I don't say the needed precision. This formula will be used in a library, and the user of the library will use as many iterations as they like. Just like the vector normalization problem: sometimes one iteration is enough, sometimes two. But still, two iterations is faster than the proper 1/sqrt way.

Comment: @njuffa: and yes, maybe the answer to this question is "there is no such formula". I'm absolutely happy with that.

Answer (score 5):

**Update** after your edit:

I reckon you have to compute values $e^x$ many times for nonnegative $x$-values in some large range. Then, following John Hughes'answer, I suggest the following: Prepare with as high precision as possible once and for all a table of the values $$a_n=e^{2^n}\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$ The $a_n$ can be computed using the recursion
$$a_0:=e,\qquad a_{n+1}:=\bigl(a_n\bigr)^2\quad(n\geq1)\ .$$
One has, e.g., $a_9\approx2.3\cdot10^{222}$.

The computation of $e^x$ for a given $x\geq0$ then proceeds as follows: Write $x$ in the form 
$$x=j+\xi,\qquad{\rm where}\quad  j:=\lfloor x\rfloor,\quad\xi:=\{x\}\ .$$
Since $0\leq \xi<1$ you can easily compute $\eta:=e^\xi$ to high precision using the Taylor series. Concerning $j$, write $j$ in binary:
$$j=\sum_{k=0}^m b_k2^k, \qquad b_k\in\{0,1\}\ .$$
Then (pick up the factors in increasing order!)
$$e^x=\eta\>\prod_{b_k=1} a_k\ .$$
**Original answer:**

The exponential series can be morphed into the following recursive scheme:
$$s_{-1}:=0,\quad s_0:=1,\qquad s_n:=s_{n-1}+{x\over n}(s_{n-1}-s_{n-2})\quad (n\geq1)\ .$$

Comment: Interesting scheme! Thanks for it. Please see my edited question. Is it possible to transform this scheme, so only one previous $s$ value is needed?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Your proposed iteration using $\,\log\,$ only requires a fast way to calculate $\,\log.\,$ This is possible using the AGM method as explained in section $7.5.2$ of *Elementary Functions: Algorithms and Implementation* by Jean-Michel Muller or some other method you can choose.
The AGM method gives a fast way of computing $\,F(x)\,$ the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. If
 $\, F(k^2) := \int_0^{\pi/2} dt/\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 t}, \,$
then the AGM can be used to compute it quickly. The function $\,F(k^2)\,$ has an approximation at $\,1^-\,$ given by $\, F(1 - (4/x)^2) \approx \log(x) + 4(\log(x)-1)/x^2. \,$ This method may not be ideal, but it can be used.

The same book in section $7.5.3$ **Computing Exponentials with the AGM** has iteration $(7.14)$ $\, x_{n+1} = x_n(1 + a - \ln(x_n)) \,$ for computing $\, \exp(a). \,$

Note that the AGM is used for fast methods to compute a number of elementary functions and $\pi.$ Of course, there are other methods, such as CORDIC. You can experiment with them. No matter how you compute logarithms, you can use that in your iteration for the exponential.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. (7.14) is the same expression that I presented in my answer. (note: I reverted back your modification, as $n$ was the same variable as $a$ in (7.14). calling it $x$ is misleading)

Comment: Your formula. You will see if it is correct immediately f you try using it.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, you're right, I didn't check the left hand side.

Comment: As I investigated, your proposed method could work, but unfortunately I don't get what I want with it. The main reason of my approximation was to calculate $e^x$ really fast. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: The point of the book and that section was to compute $\,\exp(x)\,$ **fast** and with arbitrary precision. Just google AGM exponential and you will see.

Comment: Yes, but it is slower/same speed than current 32-bit/64-bit floating point libraries. My main objective is to avoid computing it altogether. Like for example, if you have an almost unit length vector, then calculating `1/sqrt(length)` is not needed, because the vector can be normalized with a crude approximation of 1/sqrt.

Comment: Wait...you were hoping to get a way to compute exponentials *faster* than the standard floating point libraries? Those things that have been worked on and developed by some of the world's best numerical analysts? Perhaps I can get you a rainbow with a pot of gold next to it as well...

Comment: @JohnHughes: yes, because I already have a good approximation to begin with. Like my vector normalization example. An almost unit length vector can be normalized faster then the usual 1/sqrt(length) way, if we know that the vector is very near to be unit length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Taylor Series for the Exponential Function

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this is not a solution for my problem (as far as I know). I've edited my question a little bit, so hopefully it is more clear what I need.

Comment: To minimize the number of Taylor series terms in high-precision computation, it can be advantageous to compute $\exp(x) = \mathrm{sinh}(x) + \sqrt{1 + [\mathrm{sinh}(x)]^2}$. The square root can be computed iteratively via simpler elementary operations.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you can use the Taylor series...but if you try to compute $e^{100}$ that way, you'll need a great many terms. Fortunately, you can instead compute $e^{50}$ and square the result. Or $e^{25}$ and square it twice. Or $e^{0.5}$, and raise it to the $200$ power. The advantage of this last one is that the numerator ($0.5^k$) gets small very fast, while the denominator gets large very fast, so you get very rapid convergence.

The disadvantage is that when you compute your result $r \approx e^{0.5}$, you find that $r^{200}\approx e^{100}$ contains an error that's substantially larger than the error in $r$, and you really need to do some calculus to decide what the optimal number of terms to use in computing $r$ might be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this is not a solution for my problem (as far as I know). I've edited my question a little bit, so hopefully it is more clear what I need.

Comment: It's a solution to the question you actually asked (and seem to still be asking -- see the first sentence). I leave it to others to solve the problem you meant to ask but cannot seem to quite write down. I'm OK at math, but not mindreading. :)

Comment: I'd like to use an initial guess. I don't know how to use an initial guess with Taylor series.

Comment: One way to use it is to throw it away. :)

Comment: That's the whole point... I don't want to throw it away, because that is the key to compute it fast. Of course, if there exists a simple, fast formula, which can refine an approximation. Like my formula with $\ln$, but faster (i.e., no $\ln$ in it, just basic operations).