# Is there any *efficient* polynomial recursive formula that converges to $\exp(x)$?

Tags: limits, polynomials, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

I want to know if there's a recursive formula defined as polynomials with suitable initial conditions so that it converges to $\exp(x)$ for given $x$. More precisely, I wonder if there exists

1. (initial condition) $a_{0}, ..., a_{N-1}$
2. (recursive relation) $a_{n} = F(a_{n-1}, \dots, a_{n-N};x)$ where $F: \mathbb{R}^{N+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a (low-degree) polynomial.
3. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = \exp(x)$ for given $x$ (so the initial conditions or the polynomial $F$ may depends on given $x$).

One may say the Taylor expansion, which can be considered as $a_{0} = 1$ and $F(a_{n-1};x) = a_{n-1} + \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$. However, this is not appropriate for my purpose since the degree of polynomial $F$ grows linearly with $n$ (I hope $F$ to have a bounded degree). I found one candidate in Christian's answer for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846552/iterative-calculation-of-ex) MSE question, but I don't know how fast the $a_{n}$ converges to $\exp(x)$. It would be great if someone suggests a better formula which converges very fast with low-degree $F$.

---

Edit: I found that the formula mentioned in the above MSE question is just a different expression for the Taylor series of $\exp(x)$, so that it would converge quite fast (at least on a bounded interval). But I still want to know if there's a better choice.

Comment: For which $x$ do you need convergence? The Taylor expansion converges fairly quickly close to the point where derivatives are taken (ie x=0 in your example). Convergence on the entire real line doesn't really work because any polynomial grows much slower than exp for large x.

Comment: @quarague I agree with you. I think the Taylor expansion is a pretty good choice, but I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: Note that if ones requires all $F$ to be the same, then $a = \exp(x)$ neccessarily will be a root of $a = F(a, a, \dots, a; x)$. Thus $a$ is an algebraic number which $e = \exp(1)$ is not, for example. The Taylor approach works because $F$ is different for each iteration

Comment: @uranix I think that may not be the true, since $F(a, a, \dots, a;x)$ could be identically $a$.